# NullOrEmpty value dosent respond

Tags: c#

I have 2 textboxes, where if they are empty, it automatically should respond "Unknown" in the textboxes, but they just remain empty, with this code I have made

```
private void btnSaveAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPhoneAddress.Text)))
        {
            txtPhoneAddress.Text = "Unknown";
        }


        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMailAddress.Text)))
        {
            txtMailAddress.Text = "Unknown";
        }

        try
        {
            addressesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            addressesTableAdapter.Update(this.appData14.Addresses);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            addressesBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are checking if the textbox is **not** null or empty.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then your logic is wrong: `if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMailAddress.Text)))` should be `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMailAddress.Text) == true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPhoneAddress.Text)
```

instead of

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPhoneAddress.Text)
```

Otherwise you won't fill data when textbox is `empty` or `null`

`string.IsNullOrEmpty` will return `true` when the arg string is `null` or empty.

Comment: Oh, i will try that ;) 2 sec

Comment: That worked! Thanks, i will mark your answer, as an answer in 8 minutes, when the website allow me to do it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are checking for the opposite of what you actually want. 
You check if a Textbox is not empty nad if that is the case you set the text to unknown.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox control's Text property cannot be null. Only it can be empty (""). But you should trim before checking if Textbox is empty.

```
if(txtPhoneAddress.Text.Trim() == ""){
      txtPhoneAddress.Text = "Unknown";
}
```